# WSO2 ESB with DSS integrated doesn't response JSON

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server

I have a WSO2 ESB server with DSS features installed. When I invoke a REST service with "accept: application/json" in request header, I don't receive JSON response, only XML.

Comment: Hi Ivan, could you share the code of your proxy service please?

Answer (score 2):

In this API, to get the response in JSON, I use these two properties:

```
<property name="Accept" value="application/json" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

You can see the implementation here

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="showById" context="/getById">
   <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/getEmployeeXML/{Id}">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="getId" expression="get-property('uri.var.Id')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log>
            <property name="ID" expression="get-property('getId')"/>
         </log>
         <property name="Accept" value="application/json" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:getEmployeeXML xmlns:p="arce.farmacy">
                  <xs:Id xmlns:xs="arce.farmacy">$1</xs:Id>
               </p:getEmployeeXML>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('getId')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="Action" value="urn:getEmployeeXML" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="SOAPAction" value="urn:getEmployeeXML" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
          <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://169.254.193.10:9763/services/StoredProcedureFarmacy" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <sequence key="{faultSEQ}"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

This is the response

```
{
  "Employees": {
    "Employe": [
      {
        "Id": 5,
        "Description": "Office 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```